# Remove the space from a regex match while user types in an input box

Tags: javascript, regex

If the user types:

```
my name is jackson5 model number 5g1 |nR%1b and I would 644 like to say 55 hello to all the tags of html in the world.
```

I'd like to replace the 55 hello with 55hello while they continue to type with no hiccups or interuptions to the input box.

here is my code so far. I have the regex statement in there but not sure how to replace the space between 55 hello so that it becomes 55hello.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function isValid(strQuery){ 
    var regStatement =/[0-9]+ hello/;
   if (regStatement.test(strQuery.value)) { 
    strQuery.value = strQuery.value.replace("$2","");
    }
 }
</script>

<input type="text" id="wtf" name="search_query" onkeyup="isValid(this);" />
```

Comment: I think this topic matches your question and should answer it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217176/changing-input-value-while-still-allowing-the-user-to-type

Comment: If you make the regex of two capture groups e.g. `([0-9]+) (hello)` then you can use the contents of the two capture groups to construct what you want to replace it with.

Comment: patashu thanks man I get it now. how can i accept your answer?

Comment: @Neil I don't know the syntax, so feel free to post an answer with how you solved it and self-accept.

Comment: are you sure? you pretty much told me the answer, i had to make the two groups.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function isValid(strQuery){ 
    strQuery.value = strQuery.value.replace(/((\d+)\s+)(?=hello)/,"$2");
}
```

you don't need to test it first, if the string doesn't match, it won't replace anything.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to post comments, so I will have to resort to an 'answer' -- be careful with this approach. I've tested my solution and also that posted by @leonhart above (his is much better, so I will not bother posting mine). What both have in common is that both cause TWO calls to isValid, in case if your input box has a history of similar inputs, and starts to provide suggestions (didn't occur in Chrome, but did in Firefox). Not sure what's causing it, but, apparently, either the event handler is registered twice, or something along those lines.. good luck figuring that out! Or maybe someone else here can explain the cause... and the workaround =)